# K6 response body check

Tags: javascript, k6

I'm using k6 to test a token generator.
I want to add a check to filter the success response with status code 200 and token must exist.

My current script is

```
  check(response, {
    "status equals 200": response => response.status.toString() === "200",
    "body contains access_token": response =>
      response.body.includes("access_token"),
  });
```

but it does not work and return an error

```
level=error msg="failed to handle the end-of-test summary" error="error handling summary object body contains access_token: invalid type map[string]interface {}, it needs to be a string, byte array or an ArrayBuffer"
```

[Response example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E67p6.png)

Thank you guys for helping me !!

Comment: Do you have a custom `handleSummary` function exported? The code looks fine, but the error is from the Go runtime. What happens when you remove this single check or replace it with a dummy check, e.g. `"body contains access_token" => true`?

Comment: This code I generated from the generator provided by k6. . It's worked fine when I remove "body contains" condition.

Comment: Are you using the latest k6 version? If not, try the latest. If you already are, try an older version.